# Does the iOS version of Chrono Trigger put save games in the cloud?

Tags: ios, chrono-trigger

I am interested in purchasing [*Chrono Trigger* for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chrono-trigger/id479431697), but before investing in the game was trying to ascertain if save games were placed in the cloud<sup>1</sup>. I have a variety of iOS devices and can never be sure which one I'm going to have with me. Ideally my game progress would not tied to anyone device. Even though the game is listed as Game Center compatible the feature bullet doesn't elaborate in what way.

Are *Chrono Trigger* save games pushed to the cloud so that games in progress can be resumed from any iOS device?

<sub>1. I too hate the cloud marketing buzz word, but couldn't think of a more appriopriate term. :(</sub>

Comment: If it supports iCloud pushing it is usually on the app's info page. iCloud may only be usable with the general iCloud sync instead.

Comment: @CyberSkull what do you mean by "general ICloud sync?"

Comment: iOS can back up all application data to iCloud without the application's prompting. When an app supports iCloud push, the app sends the data to iCloud directly instead of waiting for the daily sync to occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrono Trigger for iOS does not 'sync' to iCloud in the way you are hoping.

I've played on my phone and seen that the save game does not sync my iPad.

To check for other games/apps (if you own them) look under Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage.

The apps listed under 'Documents & Data' sync between devices.

The apps listed under your device's name are backed up, but not synced via iCloud unless they are also in the previously mentioned list.

Some games/apps sync using cloud servers other than iCloud (Eg: Dropbox). In this case, they would appear in the back-up list, but not the Documents & Data list, but would still be syncing.

Chrono Trigger isn't one of those.

You could restore from a backup and thus transfer your save game to a different device, but that isn't the situation you're describing.